# Python: questions about format in SVM coding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I want to use svm to do supervised machine learning. My project is: Given Obama's several speeches, and  Romney's several speeches, the classifier can decide which speaker spoke this speech when we input an unknown speech.

The code on the site wrote like this:  SVC, NuSVC and LinearSVC take as input two arrays: an array **X** of size **[n_samples, n_features]** holding the training samples, and an array **Y** of **integer values**, **size [n_samples]**, holding the class labels for the training samples:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> y = [0, 1]
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
gamma=0.0, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

After being fitted, the model can then be used to predict new values:

```
>>> clf.predict([[2., 2.]])
array([1])
```

**My question**: 
**1.In my project, in**

```
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Should I replace the first number in each square bracket with label ‘Obama’ or 'Romeny'.

**2.And how about**

```
y = [0, 1]
```

The component should be replaced by 'Obama' or 'Romney', either?  But it should be integer number based on the code annotation above.

**3.And about the content in the clf.predict()**

```
clf.predict([[2., 2.]])
```

Shouldn't be just your extracted feature of your input, then the classifier decide which category(obama or romney) it belongs to. Why there is two component?

Answer (score 2):

Question #1: No.  Your X should contain the information you want to use to predict who gave the speech.  Presumably this will be dervied somehow from the text of the speech.  Take a look at [the text feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) for some ideas.

Question #2: Yes, because y is what you want to predict, and you want to predict whether it was Obama or Romney.

Question #3: There are two components because in that example the input has two features.  Your data may have any number of features.  If you're using text data to predict something, you will usually have a lot of features (in the simplest case, one feature per distinct word in the texts, although you may trim this down by eliminating some words, like frequent function words such as "the").

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @BrenBarn！ For the Question #1, what you mean is all the components in the square bracket are extracted feature. But the annotation of code said "an array X of size [n_samples, n_features] holding the training samples"  So I am wondering if the first component in the square bracket is the number of the imput or label something?

Comment: And for the extracted feature, it can be stirng format, right? no necessary to be numerical number.

Comment: scikit-learn classifiers all accept string labels. Until last week, the SVM docs were wrong on this, but string labels have been supported for several released (and the last release was a year ago).

Comment: @user3746295: I don't understand what you're asking.  In your example, X has two rows and two columns, because there are two samples and two features.  As for your second comment, no.  As larsmans noted, the category *labels* (i.e., Obama/Romney) can be strings, but the *features* that you use to predict the labels must be numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Python for machine learning, but I believe list **Y** is out outcome labels. You might already know this-- **X** is a list of lists, like a matrix, called the *features*.

For text mining, you create a a feature from the text of each speech. These features become the input used to train your SVM. Before training the SVM, look into how to create a feature. A simple technique for text mining is the bag-of-words. Check it out here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words.

If using bag-of-words, your feature vectors might look like this:

[[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

The first list represents the words in one speech, the second list represents the words in another speech. There is one feature for every speech in your training set.

Your **Y** vector is the outcomes. Let's say "0" means "loser" and "1" means "winner". If the first speech was the winner and the second speech was the loser, then **Y** would be:

[1, 0]

Comment: Thank youv very much for your reply. I am wondering where can I download the dictionary to use bag of words model?

Comment: I do not know how the experts do it, but the simplest thing that would works is: (1) find ALL words in every of the speeches. (2) Sort the words. (3) Remove duplicate words. (4) Use the position of the word as an index into a List. For example, if the third word in your sorted list is "apple" and speech #5 uses the word "apple" 10 times, then set featureMatrix[5][3] = 10. Of course, there are more clever ways to do it. Go the Wikipedia article I referenced and read the section "Hashing trick". Also, if you liked my answer, please accept the answer by clicking the gray check mark next to it.